# Ханойская башня с массивами C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, рекурсия

Можете объяснить мне как реализовать это с массивами, представьте эти стержни и кольца так:

```
5,4,3,2,1
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
```

Тем же методом которую мы делаем в Ханойских башнях делаем и здесь и итог должен выглядеть так:

```
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
5,4,3,2,1
```

Уже третий день я ломаю голову над этим

Условия которые может делать совершать программа с массивами:
- Можно за одно действие брать из массива только одно число;
- Брать элемент массива можно только с конца;
- Перебрасывать значение из одного массива можно только в другой массив; 
- При перебрасывание, значение пропускает все нули в конец;
- Число можно перебросить в другой массив, только в условии есть позиция куда оно попадает будет соответствовать требованию что элемент слева больше чем наше значение;

Comment: Непонятно. Где стержни, где кольца? Какие правила перестановок?

Comment: это 3 массива {5,4,3,2,1}{0,0,0,0,0}{0,0,0,0,0}

Comment: здесь числа выступают как кольца самое большое число это самый большое кольцо, а сами массивы они стержни

Comment: {5,4,3,2,1}                       {0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0}    ====>>>>  {0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0}                       {5,4,3,2,1}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вроде [так](https://ideone.com/4hwGNL), нет?

```
int A[5] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
int B[5], C[5];

void print()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) cout << A[i] << " "; cout << "  ";
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) cout << B[i] << " "; cout << "  ";
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) cout << C[i] << " "; cout << endl;
}

void move(int count, int * F, int * T, int * A)
{
    if (count == 0) return;
    move(count-1, F, A, T);
    //F -> T
    int t = 4; while(T[t]==0 && t >= 0) t--;
    int f = 4; while(F[f]==0) f--;
    T[t+1] = F[f];
    F[f] = 0;

    print();
    move(count-1, A, T, F);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    print();
    move(5,A,C,B);
    print();
}
```

Comment: О май гад, ты прям красавчик огромное спасибо братан щас я разберусь  с кодом, не хочу чтобы не понимая я тупо копи пастил в мое задание и сдать учителю я хочу понять что там происходит

Comment: Ну вот, вместо чтоб птичку у ответа нажать, гадом обозвали :) Та же рекурсия, что и в Ханойской башне, только перенос верхнего диска - его приходится искать (наверняка можно и проще, но мне в этот вечерний час уже просто лом...)

Comment: Сорян бро я забыл но только что поставил галочку, и да спасибо за объяснение ;)